# Проблема с отображением html в хроме

Tags: html, css, vue.js

Решил я попрактиковаться на Vue.js и сделал себе html, css для примера. У меня возникла проблема, что html вообще очень странно отображается.

1. Теги html и body вообще куда-то ускакали[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И никак не могу их поставить на место

2. Вообще не работает свойство height для body
3. При width: 100% у body появляется полоса прокрутки

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/logo.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Уроки Vue.js</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="vue">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
</body>

<script src="vue.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(255, 180, 153);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#vue {
    width: 45%;
    height: 30%;
    background-color: rgb(255, 144, 103);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    margin: 100px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    border-radius: 7px;

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -ms-border-radius: 7px;
    -o-border-radius: 7px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать высоту в vh

```
body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 180, 153);
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#vue {
  width: 45%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 144, 103);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
```

Comment: неа, не работает(

Comment: Поправил код выше.

Comment: Впринципе сработало, спасибо большое